# using function without argument

Tags: bash, function

Let's take a little example:

```
$ cat fu.sh
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

function lsl () {
   ls -1
}

function grps () {
  lsl | grep fu.sh
}

echo "This file is: `grps`"
```

Let's run it to see it works as we want:

```
$ ./fu.sh
This file is: fu.sh
```

So - we have function `lsl` which called from second function `grps`. Also - we called  function `grps` alone at the end of script.

Here is a question - is there anything "*unusual*", "*unsafe*" or may be "*irritant*" and "*not Feng Shui*" - call function without any option or argument passed to it?

Comment: Your question is definitely not `bash`-specific, but no - there is nothing wrong with such a function, *as long as the function does exactly what you intended for it to do*.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with it. if you need a function and you don't need arguments, that's what you're going to use.

Comment: On a related note, avoid using both the `function` keyword and brackets (cf. [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#function_foo.28.29)).

Comment: @mtth thanks a lot, don't know about it...

Comment: and the function is not very useful: if you rename your script to "foo.sh" and forget to edit the inside, it will be incorrect. You cuold just do: `function grps () { echo "$(basename "$0")" ; }`  instead

Comment: Thanks, @OlivierDulac - but I wrote this one just for this very question and just as example :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is noting wrong in the script. It will work properly.
You need to go through basics of shell scripting.